# Windows phone 8 app bar command parameter always null - Cimbalino

Tags: windows-phone, winrt-xaml, mvvm-light, windows-phone-toolkit, cimbalino

**Xaml Namespaces**

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
                        xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                        xmlns:appBar="clr-namespace:Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Behaviors;assembly=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit"
                        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP8"



<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>




    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">

        <TextBlock Text="Beneficiary"
                   Margin="9,-7,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector
                           x:Name="beneficoryList"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding BeneficoryCollection}"
                            EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsSelectionEnabled, ElementName=LayoutRoot,Mode=TwoWay}">

            <!--Is Selection Enabled Changed Command-->
            <!--<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="IsSelectionEnabledChanged">
                    <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.IsSelectionEnabledChangedOn,ElementName=LayoutRoot,Mode=OneTime}"/>
                </interactivity:EventTrigger>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>-->


            <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operator}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                        <!-- Interaction region-->
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <!-- Interaction region ends-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>

        </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
    </Grid>
</Grid>  
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior x:Name="appBar" IsVisible="True"
                                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"
                                       ForegroundColor="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundColor}" Mode="Default">



            <appBar:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"
                                       IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Add.png"
                                       IsVisible="{Binding IsAddCommandVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                       Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>

            <appBar:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Delete"
                                         IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Delete.png"
                                         Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,Mode=OneTime}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=beneficoryList}"/>


            <!--Menu Items-->
            <appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior.MenuItems>
                <appBar:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="HelpDesk" />
                <appBar:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Contact Us"/>
            </appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior.MenuItems>
            <!--Menu Items End-->

        </appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior>

    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

**View Model**

```
private RelayCommand<object> _ondeleteCommand;

    public RelayCommand<object> DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return _ondeleteCommand ?? (_ondeleteCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(OnDeleteCommand)); }
    }



    private void OnDeleteCommand(object tobeDeleted)
    {
        if (tobeDeleted != null)
        {
           // Delete
        }
    }
```

How do I pass selectedItems of LongListMultiSelector to a command .In the command argument I always getting null. there is no binding errors in the output window.

[Cimbalino Guide](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/03/11/cimbalino-windows-phone-toolkit-multiapplicationbarbehavior/)

Comment: I've beeen trying to figure this out for a few days myself. I think it should be possible, but everything I've found says that it's not. You're best bet is to bind what you need to your View Model elsewhere and access it in there when this command is called.

Comment: @Poken1151 I figured out , what I done wrong , I moved the app bar inside the grid , where I could find my listbox.. I appreciate your effort , thank you

Comment: I'll have to give Cimbalino a try. I can't do this with the Bindable Application Bar. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @Poken1151, Cimbalino is awesome , do you have any idea about creating a local toast without background agent . I want to show a toast when app is foreground ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
                        xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                        xmlns:appBar="clr-namespace:Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Behaviors;assembly=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit"
                        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP8"


 <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--App Bar Binding-->
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior x:Name="appBar" IsVisible="True"
                                       BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"
                                       ForegroundColor="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundColor}" Mode="Default">



            <appBar:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Add"
                                       IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Add.png"
                                       IsVisible="{Binding IsAddCommandVisible,Mode=TwoWay}"  
                                       Command="{Binding AddCommand}"/>

            <appBar:ApplicationBarIconButton Text="Delete"
                                         IconUri="/Toolkit.Content/ApplicationBar.Delete.png"
                                         Command="{Binding DeleteCommand,Mode=OneTime}"
                                         CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems,ElementName=beneficoryList}"/>


            <!--Menu Items-->
            <appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior.MenuItems>
                <appBar:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="HelpDesk" />
                <appBar:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Contact Us"/>
            </appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior.MenuItems>
            <!--Menu Items End-->

        </appBar:ApplicationBarBehavior>

    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>


    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Margin="12,17,0,28">

        <TextBlock Text="Beneficiary"
                   Margin="9,-7,0,0"
                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector
                           x:Name="beneficoryList"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding BeneficoryCollection}"
                            EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="{Binding DataContext.IsSelectionEnabled, ElementName=LayoutRoot,Mode=TwoWay}">
            <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMedium}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Operator}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}"/>
                        <!-- Interaction region-->
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                                <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                            </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <!-- Interaction region ends-->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>

        </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>


    </Grid>


</Grid>
```

The element 'beneficoryList' is not finding in the visual tree, I was placed the app bar outside of the grid , **Now I moved the App-bar inside the grid** so 'beneficoryList' is now selectedItems is passed to VM . I think WP only allow traversing to just its immediate parent

Comment: You can still use it on the root element, just as long as you understand that it's a different Xaml Namescope and use the `NamescopeBinding` helper; more information on this here: https://www.pedrolamas.com/2013/05/02/understanding-xaml-namescopes/